# COM: Create a VT_ARRAY with VT_BSTR values

Tags: com

I'm a COM newbie and I think what I have is correct, but the runtime doesn't like it. Any help is much appreciated.

I need to invoke a COM function that takes in a single dimensional array of BSTRs. Specifically, the documentation says the parameter must be:

> Function: AddFiles  (  [in] VARIANT *  filePaths )
>
> *filePaths*  The single-dimensioned array of full paths to each file or
>   folder. filePaths can be of type
>   `VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT`, where each entry
>   is a `VT_BSTR`, or `VT_ARRAY|VT_BSTR`.

I have a `vector<wstring> myPaths` of paths which I want to pass into the function that takes the parameter above. Here's the code I wrote. Calling AddFiles on myComObject results in an AV (myComObject is not null, and I can invoke other methods on it):

```
        ...
        VARIANT filePaths;
        VariantInit( &filePaths );
        filePaths.vt = VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT;
        filePaths.parray = SafeArrayCreateVector( VT_BSTR, 0, (unsigned int) myPaths.size() );

        long i = 0;
        for( vector<wstring>::iterator it = myPaths.begin();
            it != myPaths.end();
            it++, i++ )
        {
            BSTR myPath= SysAllocString(it->c_str());
            SafeArrayPutElement( filePaths.parray, &i, myPath);
        }

        myComObject->AddFiles( &filePaths );
        ...
```

The COM object isn't my code and I can't debug into it, but I suspect I'm not creating that array properly - based on the requirement of the AddFiles function and the code I have, anyone have ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You have a memory leak in the loop -- SafeArrayPutElement copies the incoming BSTR, so you need to make sure you SysFreeString myPath after adding it to the array.

Comment: I thought invoking SafeArrayDestroy at the end would clean up the BSTR... not true?

Comment: From MSDN for SafeArrayDestroy: "Safe arrays of variant will have VariantClear called on each member and safe arrays of BSTR will have SysFreeString called on each element"

Comment: Yes, it will destroy its own copy. SafeArrayPutElement does not take ownership of the BSTR you pass to it, but rather it makes a copy. So your original BSTR still needs to be deallocated.

Comment: Thank you! <appeasing the comment length Gods>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If myComObject->AddFiles can only deal with VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT, the following should work too.

```
VARIANT myPath;
VariantInit(&myPath);

myPath.vt = VT_BSTR;
myPath.bstrVal = SysAllocString(it->c_str());

SafeArrayPutElement(filePaths.parray, &i, &myPath);
```

Comment: If so, you also need to say VT_VARIANT when creating the SAFEARRAY with SafeArrayCreateVector.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you want:

```
filePaths.vt = VT_ARRAY|VT_BSTR;
```

Since you're creating a SafeArray of BSTRs?

Comment: So, try leaving it as `VT_ARRAY|VT_VARIANT` and then pack each string into a variant instead in the loop as suggested by taichicat below.