# pinvoke - pass a string[] as out parameter

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke

I couldn't get the below p/invoke code working, please help, thanks.

vertices below stays as null after the c++ call. I've tried to use IntPtr instead of string[], IntPtr stays as 0 after c++ call.

c++ code

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)
float compute_similarity(char** vertices)
{       
  vertices = new char*[2];
  vertices[0] = new char[3];
  vertices[1] = new char[3];

  strcpy(vertices[0], "he");
  strcpy(vertices[1], "ha");

  return 1.01;
}
```

c# code

```
[DllImport("demo.dll", EntryPoint = "compute_similarity", 
    CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl,   CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern float compute_similarity(out string[] vertices);  
//also tried 'static extern float compute_similarity(out IntPtr vertices);'  

public string Func()
{
  string[] vertices; //also tried 'IntPtr vertices'
  float sim = compute_similarity(out vertices); 
  //break point here vertices stays null(or 0 for IntPtr)
  return sim.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can't see an issue with your c++ code. I copy/pasted it and replaced passed in parameter with a local char** and it worked fine for me. How are you calling the function compute_similarity()? (what are you passing in to it?)

Comment: This code cannot reliably be called from C++, it doesn't get better when you call it from C#.  The caller *has* to call delete[] to get the memory for the array released.  That sometimes works from C++, you need a fair amount of luck and carefully control the compiler version that's used by both the DLL and the client code.  It is guaranteed to not work from C#, it doesn't know how to call the C++ delete[] operator.  You got 0 because your C++ code is bad, the vertices argument should be char***.

Comment: First make your function work for C++ client. It looks like you need char*** - great design!

Comment: @AlexFarber yes, tested its working in c++ client. instead of using char** any suggestions on what other parameter type i can use that works for p/invoke? thanks

Comment: compute_similarity allocates char** pointer, but client doesn't see this, because pointer is passed by value.

Comment: @Xin A SAFEARRAY could probably work.

Comment: After fixing C++ code write C# client using low-level Marshal functions. IntPtr + Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr, Int32) + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr) allow to work with pointers like in C. Write also unmanaged function that releases this pointer properly, and call it after using resources allocated by compute_similarity.

Comment: PInvoke definintion should be compute_similarity(out IntPtr ptr);

Comment: @Medinoc your code in your answer is working. thanks

Comment: Oops, my previous code contained a memory leak because according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456400/com-create-a-vt-array-with-vt-bstr-values#comment1326897_1456400 SafeArrayPutElement does not take ownership of the BSTR. I've corrected my code sample, make sure to correct your actual code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be done properly this way, because you have no way of specifying that P/Invoke must free the memory with `delete[]` calls after converting it to managed strings.

However, with a `SAFEARRAY` of `BSTR`s and the `MarshalAs` attribute, you may have a fighting chance.

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)
float compute_similarity(SAFEARRAY** vertices)
{
    SAFEARRAY *pArr = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_BSTR, 0, 2);
    if(pArr != NULL)
    {
        LONG index = 0;
        BSTR bs = SysAllocString(L"he");
        SafeArrayPutElement(pArr, &index, bs);
        SysFreeString(bs);
        index = 1;
        bs = SysAllocString(L"ha");
        SafeArrayPutElement(pArr, &index, bs);
        SysFreeString(bs);
    }
    *vertices = pArr;
    return 1.01;
}
```

```
[DllImport("demo.dll", EntryPoint = "compute_similarity", CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern float compute_similarity(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] out string[] vertices
);
```

---

Of you may still use `IntPtr` (and do the marshaling manually on the C# side, while exporting a `delete_strings` function), but remember that your function must take its `char**` by reference, or it can't actually modify it.